# mysql query is returning error #1054

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error and i don't know what to do

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'ple.playlists' in 'on clause'
```

Please help, I'm testing directly in phpMyAdmin, heres my query:

```
SELECT
  u.`idu` AS `user_id`,
  u.`username` AS `user_name`,
  u.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
  u.`last_name` AS `last_name`,
  u.`country` AS `user_country`,
  u.`image` AS `user_image`,
  u.`cover` AS `user_cover`,
  u.`description` AS `user_description`,
  pl.`id` AS `playlist_id`,
  pl.`name` AS `playlist_name`,
  t.`id` AS `track_id`,
  t.`title` AS `track_title`,
  t.`name` AS `track_name`,
  t.`art` AS `track_art`,
  t.`likes` AS `track_likes`,
  t.`downloads` AS `track_downloads`,
  t.`views` AS `track_plays`
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN playlists AS pl
  ON u.idu=pl.by
INNER JOIN playlistentries AS ple
  ON pl.id=ple.playlists
INNER JOIN tracks AS t
  ON ple.track=t.id
ORDER BY `user_id` ASC, `playlist_id` ASC, `track_id` ASC
```

Comment: Please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE playlistentries`. Are you sure the name of the field is `playlists`, not singular `playlist`?

Comment: Or maybe it's `playlist_id`.

Comment: Thank you... it was ple.playlist @Barmar

Comment: Computer programming requires attention to detail. While it's understandable that you make typos like this, the error message should have clued you in to it.